# Libgdx sprite rotation (image quality)

Tags: libgdx, rotation, spritebatch

This one is probably really simple but I didn't find a solution.

I'm trying to create a widget (speedometer) with libgdx.
For the arrows I'm using the `setRotation()` function.
But when the image is rotated, the quality drops.

The result looks like this:

[image: Speedometer]

How can I improve the quality of the arrows?

Comment: not sure if libgdx has this but in java I use g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY); and that helps improve the rotated image quality a lot

Comment: You can also look at your texture filtering and anti-aliasing settings.

Comment: Yay! Thank you Roy! **.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);** fixed this! :)

Comment: @RoyT. add it as an answer, please :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Roy T. suggested to fix this changing the texture filtering settings,
On LibGDX this can be found on [`Texture.setFilter`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/GLTexture.html#setFilter%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter,%20com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter%29) or changing the [`Texture Params`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/loaders/TextureLoader.TextureParameter.html) if you are using the `AssetLoader`. Set the filter params to `TextureFilter.Linear` and the problem should be fixed.

For more on the matter, take a look at http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-six-an-introduction-to-texture-filtering/